# Element-wise equality in 3-D array with arbitrarily sized axes

Tags: python, numpy, equality

I am looking for an efficient way to find element-wise equality in a 3D or N-D array, for example, equal value on RGB pixels of an image. Some test data:

```
a = numpy.arange(100).reshape((10,10))
b = a.copy()
c = a.copy()
b[5,5] = 1
c[6,6] = 100
d = numpy.array([a,b,c])
```

I can think of three options, the first of which does not generalize well to more dimensions:

```
equal_mask = (d[0] == d[1]) & (d[0] == d[2])
```

or

```
equal_mask = d.min(axis=0) == d.max(axis=0)
```

or, maybe better:

```
equal_mask = numpy.logical_and.reduce(d == d[0])
```

Is there a more efficient solution?

EDIT: I should clarify that I didn't mean n-D, 3-D with different length on the first axis, for example `d = numpy.array([a,b,c,a,b,c])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divakar and Colonel Beauvel's solutions both hint that I can make my solution a bit faster by skipping the check `d[0] == d[0]`:

```
numpy.logical_and.reduce(d[1:] == d[0])
```

In terms of efficiency and ability to to work on arbitrarily size axes, this still appears to be the best solution, so far...

Comment: `d[1:,:]` could be shortened as `d[1:]`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will mark my current answer as accepted, unless something better comes along.

Comment: That sounds fair to me!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one:

```
np.logical_and(*(d[0,:]==d[1:,:]))
```

Comment: What is going on here? The tuple / asterisk syntax is new to me; I'm not clear on how this is equivalent to a reduction.

Comment: It is the splat operator and it is use for unpacking. Which means you take all elements of a list and you pass them to a function. In this example, the function is `np.logical_and` and we pass elements `a` and `b` from list `[a,b]`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I had assumed. Hence it works only for the 3-D case, but not for the n-D case.

Comment: It works because `np.logical_and` accepts not only two arguments but as many as you give and proceed to an internal reduce. Hum did not look at the n-D case ...

Comment: I don't think that is the case, fails with `d = numpy.array([a,b,c,a,b,c])`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach for `nD` array cases that looks for all `0'`s diferentiations along the first axis -

```
(np.diff(d,axis=0)==0).all(0)
```

Sample run to verify results -

```
In [46]: d = np.random.randint(0,9,(3,3,5,2,3,4,2))

In [47]: out = (np.diff(d,axis=0)==0).all(0)

In [48]: np.allclose(out,(d[0] == d[1]) & (d[0] == d[2]))
Out[48]: True
```

As it turns out, this method seems to be slower than `numpy.logical_and.reduce` based method as listed in the question. So, at this point looks like sticking with it might be the way to go.

Comment: @Benjamin Ah yes, that's even smarter! Awesome job :)